# How to import specific columns and rows from Excel using Pandas

Tags: python

My excel has many columns and rows data. But I want to import specific columns and rows data.

My code:

```
L_pos_org = pd.read_excel('EXCELFILE.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1',na_values=['NA'],usecols = "M:U")
```

Above code extract the columns that I want but it also extracts all rows.

[image]

In above excel file, I am trying to extract the data of Columns M:U and rows 106:114.

How to extract this?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=read_excel#pandas.read_excel), it seems that with a recent enough version of Pandas you could extract a specific block of rows using the parameters `skiprows` and `nrows`.  I think the command would look something like

```
pd.read_excel('EXCELFILE.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1',header=None,na_values=['NA'],usecols="M:U",skiprows=range(105),nrows=9)
```